# Unable to schedule a Schengen visa appointment through VFS Italy. What are my options?

Tags: schengen, italy, vfs-global

I have to obtain my Schengen visa through the Italian embassy on the VFS global website. I am from Melbourne, Australia; my travel dates are in August, so the earliest I could apply is in May.

I am trying to book an appointment on the VFS website and it gives me an error stating "**There are no open seats available for selected center - Italy Visa Application Centre, Melbourne**".

What does this mean? It does not display a calendar and I have heard that the VFS website has technical/system issues. Does this mean there are no appointments available with VFS Melbourne?

It doesn't seem possible, when you can only apply 3 months ahead, that there would be no appointments available now for travel in August.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie OP is probably a resident, but not a citizen

Answer (score 1):

> What does this mean? It does not display a calendar and I have heard
>   that the VFS website has technical/system issues. Does this mean there
>   are no appointments available with VFS Melbourne?

Nobody can answer this definitively except the people at the VFS/embassy

[Re-purposed from an answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66374/trying-to-get-schengen-visa-for-france-is-consulate-appointment-broken?rq=1) for a similar problem with the French embassy appointment system

> **To move forward, you can pursue one of several options**...
>
> Start (very tactfully) haranguing them on Twitter about it.
>
> Contact the consulate using their 'contact us' details and explain
>   what the problem is. It's likely this may result in a problem ticket
>   being raised at the IT support facility.
>
> Book your appointment in Sydney.
>
> Rework your itinerary such that you will land in a different Schengen
>   member (thereby changing the cognizant issuer to say France).
>
> Keep trying and trying to wait for the site to have something
>   available.
>
> Or ask them to read this.

Comment: It's because the appointment quota for that week is full. Try on next weekend onwards ...you can book the next available date.