# Setting an appointment for France visa: "We are currently at full capacity. Please try again later."

Tags: visas, france, bookings, sydney

This question is relevant to [this similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66374/trying-to-get-schengen-visa-for-france-is-consulate-appointment-broken). I am asking this question so maybe someone who had the same problem can share their experience.

I am currently a PhD student in Sydney University, Australia. I am planning to travel to France from June 27 to July 8 to attend a conference. I have already registered for the conference and have booked my flight and accommodation.

Unfortunately, I cannot set an appointment through [their portal](https://pastel.diplomatie.gouv.fr/rdvinternet/html-4.00.03/frameset/frameset.html?lcid=1&sgid=280&suid=1) no matter how many times I try. I am disappointed and very concerned about this.

Their website says that residents of New South Wales must apply from Sydney. Has anyone had the same problem and resolved it? What choices do I have? Please let me know your possible ideas.

Comment: Which is your citizenship ? You may not need a visa for short visit.

Comment: @audionuma Thanks audionuma. Unfortunately I must get a visa.

Comment: Contact them by email?

Comment: I second it. Contact them by email. I recently got mine from SF embassy and I emailed them 3 times with questions and they replied back three times with answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with the French consulate's portal, at least the part for consular services to French citizens in HK. It is a very inflexible system. And that inflexibility is reflected in the attitude of the civil servants behind the system.

As an example, when I wanted to renew both passports at the same time, I booked online an appointment. When I met the consular officer, he refused to take my second passport. One appointment, one passport. Nothing he could, or would, do. Even though we had plenty of time on my 30-minute slot.

And that's between French citizens. I've heard plenty of horror stories from foreigners visiting, or trying to, the visa section.

Also, a common issue with French consulates is the refusal to communicate by phone or email with prospective visitors beyond giving out visiting hours and the website's address.

Your prospects to get an appointment within your timeframe don't sound good. Do try and call them. But be ready for some inflexibility...